# Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$. Do the morphism $x^p-a$ always has a root in $F$ for every $a \in F$?

Tags: field-theory

Do you have an example in which $x^p - a$ does not have a solution in $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the field $\Bbb F_p(t)$ of rational functions in $t$ with coefficients in $\Bbb F_p$, then $x^p-t$ does not have a root.

Indeed, the Frobenius endomorphism $x\mapsto x^p$ on $\Bbb F_p(t)$ sends $f(t)\mapsto f(t^p)$ for any $f(t)\in\Bbb F_p(t)$ (this is because $x^p=x$ for $x\in\Bbb F_p$). Therefore, the image of the Frobenius endomorphism is $\Bbb F_p(t^p)$, which does not contain $t$, showing that there is no $f(t)$ such that $f(t)^p=t$.

Answer (score 1):

Asking that $x^p-a$ always has a solution in $F$ is the same as asking that the Frobenius map $x\mapsto x^p$ is surjective. This is the same as asking that $F$ is perfect, so if you want an example, just pick your favorite non-perfect field, such as $\mathbb{F}_q((t))$.